# Async Map with Highland.js

Tags: javascript, stream, functional-programming, highland.js

I have a Highland stream that is periodically getting data from a server. I need to do a database lookup inside of a map. I can't find any mention of doing anything async in any of Highland's transformers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`consume`](http://highlandjs.org/#consume) to process a stream in an async manner.

```
_([1, 2, 3, 4]).consume(function(err, item, push, next) {
  // Do fancy async thing
  setImmediate(function() {
    // Push the number onto the new stream
    push(null, item);

    // Consume the next item
    next();
  });
})).toArray(function(items) {
  console.log(items); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

After using a `.map` you can use a `.sequence` as:

```
var delay = _.wrapCallback(function delay(num, cb){
    setTimeout(function(){ cb(null, num+1); }, 1000);
});

_([1,2,3,4,5]).map(function(num){
    return delay(num);
}).sequence().toArray(function(arr){ // runs one by one here
    console.log("Got xs!", arr);
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/h7baz7fa/1/).

Or with `.parallel` in parallel:

```
var delay = _.wrapCallback(function delay(num, cb){
    setTimeout(function(){ cb(null, num+1); }, 1000);
});

_([1,2,3,4,5]).map(function(num){
    console.log("got here", num);
    return delay(num);
}).parallel(10).toArray(function(arr){ // 10 at a time
    console.log("Got xs!", arr);
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/huj2pj4n/)